# Alternative to BitConverter that doesn't require fixed length, zero-padded byte arrays?

Tags: c#, bitconverter

`BitConverter.GetBytes` always returns fixed length arrays for numbers, padded with zeros so that they are precisely 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes long. Similarly, the decoding methods only accept arrays of certain lengths, depending on the size of the number.

I’d prefer that `GetBytes` returned unpadded arrays and that the decoding methods accepted unpadded arrays, so that I’m not always having to do the padding and trimming myself. For example:

- I’d like `GetBytes(100000)` to return `{ 0x01, 0x86, 0xa0 }` instead of `{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x86, 0xa0 }`
- I’d like to pass `{ 0x01, 0x86, 0xa0 }` to `ToInt32` instead of `{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x86, 0xa0 }`

Am I missing some static property or different method of BitConverter—or perhaps some other class or third-party library—that gives me what I want without having to do the padding and trimming myself?

Comment: `var result = BitConverter.GetBytes(value).SkipWhile(item => item == 0).ToArray();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that code would fail on big endian architectures.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own implementation of `GetBytes()` and `ToInt32()` for that.

```cs
public byte[] GetBytesVariableLengthArray(uint number) 
{
  return switch number
  {
    < 256 => new byte[] { i & 0xFF },
    < 65536 => new byte[] { i & 0xFF, (i >> 8) & 0xFF },
    < 65536 * 256 => new byte[] { /* ... and it goes on ... */ }
    < 65536 * 65536 => new byte[] { /* ... and on ... */ }
  };
}
```

similarly `ToInt32()`:

```
public uint ToInt32FromVariableLengthArray(byte[] bytes) 
{
  uint result = 0;
  switch (bytes.Length) 
  {
    case 4:
      result = bytes[3] << 24;
      goto case 3;
    case 3:
      result |= bytes[2] << 16;
      goto case 2;
    case 2:  
      result |= bytes[1] << 8;
      goto case 1;
    case 1:
      result |= bytes[0];
      break;
  }
  return result;
}
```